# How to install the intel wifi 6 ax200 driver to Debian buster?

Tags: debian, wifi-driver, debian-buster

I need to install the intel wifi 6 ax200 driver but have never actually installed a driver on Linux. I have the driver downloaded on my system, and it's on the name: iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode. Along with two other files one for the license and one readme

I am running:

Debian Linux 10 Buster

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you need a kernel whose version is equal or higher than 5.1. To install one, you can add [Debian Backports](https://backports.debian.org/) to your list of repositories (follow the instructions there). Then, install the version that you wish.

To install the firmware of the Intel AX200 NGW, you can also use the same repository. You just need to upgrade the "firmware-iwlwifi" package. Use this command:

```
apt-get install --target-release=buster-backports firmware-iwlwifi
```

The advantage of using this repository, instead of copying the firmware by hand, is that you will get updates automatically.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Installation of the firmware is simply:

```
    % cp iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware
```